# Creating a json file from a xml file in python with xmltodict

Tags: python, xml, json, xmltodict

I am trying to create a json file from an input xml file using xmltodict with the following code

```
import io, xmltodict, json
infile = io.open(filename_xml, 'r')
outfile = io.open(filename_json, 'w')
o = xmltodict.parse( infile.read() )
json.dump( o , outfile )
```

the last line get me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 182, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)
TypeError: must be unicode, not str
```

I guess I need to change the encoding. My initial xml file seems to be ascii. Any idea on how to make this work?
Thanks

Comment: which line gives the error?

Comment: the `json.dump( o, outfile )` line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open the file in binary mode

```
outfile = io.open(filename_json, 'wb')
```

This will allow `str` as well.

Answer (score 0):

`unicode` and `str` are two different types of objects in Python prior to version 3. You can turn your value into a `unicode` object (which is basically also a string) by coercing it:

```
my_var = unicode(my_str)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where do you think I should use the `unicode` call?

Comment: Just looking at your code I'd say as `json.dump(unicode(o), outfile)`, but you'll have to try that yourself :)

Comment: I don't have your libraries installed nor run OSX, but the error gives you a precise line number that triggers the error; maybe the code surrounding that line will shed some light on your issue.